# FSL App Action Layout

Tags: page-layout, mobile, app, field-service-lightning

Is it possible, if Radio Button is checked then a Text Field required?

[image]

We have 3 travel types, Car, Carsharing and public transport, if Car is checked the field "Mileage Start" must be required. Is there a solution without validation rule?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do this with configuration. Conditional required based on field values is not possible .

You other options are

1. Validation rule(which you have mentioned)
2. Trigger code

Comment: "Custom lightning component for the layout using record form tag" Is not possible in FSL Mobile App :/

Comment: @Werner - so you cannot insert lightning components in FSL mobile app?

Comment: Nope only Salesforce One App supports lightning components

Comment: @Werner, unfortunately there is anything else that i know of you can use to accompolish your requirement